# Copy text with html tags

Tags: jquery, quill

I'm using text editor - quilljs. The problem is that there is no possibility to POST the editor content. That's why I have to copy/clone all the editor content into fictive hidden input field and use it in order to post the text.

The problem is that I can't copy the design tags (bold, underline, etc) to the fictive input field.

What can I do?

```
<div id="standalone-container">

  <div id="editor-container"></div>

</div>          
<input type="text" name="testMsg" id="testMsg">
```

JS

```
$('#editor-container').on('keyup', function() {
  $('#testMsg').val($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: `.html()` instead of `.text()`

Comment: key up on div will not work ..

Comment: you want to copy text from text box and show on div ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

Comment: @nikunjM - from div to the input field (testMsg)

Comment: Why don't you get the editor data while submitting the form? You can get the content of the editor with getContents() function and then POST what you got.

Comment: @therealbischero - can you please write me an example? how do i get the content from div while i'm posting form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this. In my example, before submitting the form, i populated the hidden input with the editor content using jquery. You can find if it works by changing return true to false and check if the hidden input has something in it.

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    theme: 'snow'
  });
  
  $('#form').on('submit', function (){
    var content = quill.container.firstChild.innerHTML
    $('#editor-input').val(content)
    return true
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <div id="editor"></div>
  <input id="editor-input" type="hidden" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```